# Add key to React Tag dynamically

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

Have been looking for this answer in SO, but perhaps I'm not frasing it correctly or there is actually no answer yet for this.

I am using an input component that uses a key to render it valid (green border) or invalid (red border) and I would like to add it dynamically:

```
<Input type="select" valid /> //This input has green border
<Input type="select" invalid /> //This input has red border
```

Since they key valid/invalid has no value like true or false, I'm not sure how to change it dynamically through a function since as far as I'm aware, I can change values dynamically with a JSX expression, but not add a key itself.

Can you please suggest a way to add 'valid' or 'invalid' tag dynamically without value?

Answer (score 2):

"Without value" is actually not accurate. What you see there is syntactic sugar for `valid={true}` and `invalid={true}`.

So, the same can be accomplished by:

```
const valid = // whatever logic here to determine if it's valid.
<Input type="select" valid={valid} invalid={!valid} /> // Either return or assign to something.
```

Alternatively:

```
let inputProps = {type: 'select'};
if (/* whatever logic here to determine if it's valid*/) {
    inputProps.valid = true;
}
else {
    inputProps.invalid = true;
}

<Input {...inputProps} />; // Either return or assign to something.
```

But the latter is a lot more verbose.

Comment: Also, perhaps it would be better to handle this using CSS classes and the [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) package.

Comment: Great! This is it

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work but give it a try.

JSX reads properties without values/= as boolean/true.

Set null values:

```
<Input type="select" invalid={null} />
```

You can then conditionally show valid or invalid input elements